# Is it possible to run a desktop GUI VM Container on linux with any linux image

Tags: virtualization, docker, lxc, lxd

Looking for way to create virtual gui desktop container inside container e.g docker or LXD whichever is better

Comment: Docker/containers are not virtualization... They are just processes running in their filesystem/network "bubble". You could have a specific app in a container that uses an X-Server on the container host but that would be complicated to setup, and there are better alternatives (Snap/Flatpak/AppImage).

Comment: It's not really accurate to say that containers are not virtualisation. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS-level_virtualisation

Answer (score 0):

while not really made for it something that would appear like a classic VM (as outlined by @xenoid) you can achieve "a full remote desktop in the container" via xrdp, see this [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/LXD/comments/8gqzhg/running_a_desktop_environment_in_a_lxc_container/) for some details.

The TL;DR would be:

```
$ sudo apt install xrdp
$ sudo apt install xorgxrdp
$ sudo apt install xrdp-pulseaudio-installer
```

I think depending on the ubuntu version you might need to enable the services and then connect with the [RDP client](https://www.ubuntupit.com/10-fast-and-secure-remote-desktop-client-software-for-linux/) of your choice.